# I need to increase the CPU usage of my program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, time, cpu

I have a program that take an image and changes it to 1 bit B&W.  It uses Lockbyte software to make it faster.  BUT, when running it, it takes over a minute to process one image.  When looking at the CPU usage it is only 5% at most once it is running.  Is there a way to get the computer to use more CPU time?  The indicator is showing that the computer is running below 50%, as low as 25%.

I just had one DUH thought, I forgot to add the resizing function into my program.  It should help but I know I need to make the conversion faster yet.  The program will be used to do 100 to 300 images per batch.

Most other programs I have seen do a conversion within a few seconds per image.  I would like to get to something like this too.

This is the program.  Mostly cobbled together from samples.  I only half understand it but can read it.  Sorry to the contributors that I cannot give credit to them.  I didn't keep track of them.

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Function ConvertTo1Bit(ByVal input As Bitmap) As Bitmap
        Dim masks = New Byte() {&H80, &H40, &H20, &H10, &H8, &H4, &H2, &H1}
        Dim output = New Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
        Dim data = New SByte(input.Width - 1, input.Height - 1) {}
        Dim inputData = input.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, input.Width, input.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

        Try
            Dim scanLine = inputData.Scan0
            Dim line = New Byte(inputData.Stride - 1) {}
            Dim y = 0

            While y < inputData.Height
                Marshal.Copy(scanLine, line, 0, line.Length)

                For x = 0 To input.Width - 1
                    data(x, y) = CSByte((64 * (GetGreyLevel(line(x * 3 + 2), line(x * 3 + 1), line(x * 3 + 0)) - 0.5)))
                Next

                y += 1
                scanLine += inputData.Stride
            End While

        Finally
            input.UnlockBits(inputData)
        End Try

        Dim outputData = output.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, output.Width, output.Height), ImageLockMode.[WriteOnly], PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)

        Try
            Dim scanLine = outputData.Scan0
            Dim y = 0

            While y < outputData.Height
                Dim line = New Byte(outputData.Stride - 1) {}

                For x = 0 To input.Width - 1
                    Dim j = data(x, y) > 0
                    Try
                        If j Then
                            line(x / 8) = line(x / 8) Or masks(x Mod 8)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try


                    Dim [error] = CSByte((data(x, y) - (If(j, 32, -32))))
                    If x < input.Width - 1 Then data(x + 1, y) += CSByte((7 * [error] / 16))

                    If y < input.Height - 1 Then
                        If x > 0 Then data(x - 1, y + 1) += CSByte((3 * [error] / 16))
                        data(x, y + 1) += CSByte((5 * [error] / 16))
                        If x < input.Width - 1 Then data(x + 1, y + 1) += CSByte((1 * [error] / 16))
                    End If
                Next

                Marshal.Copy(line, 0, scanLine, outputData.Stride)
                y += 1
                scanLine += outputData.Stride
            End While

        Finally
            output.UnlockBits(outputData)
        End Try

        Return output
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetGreyLevel(ByVal r As Byte, ByVal g As Byte, ByVal b As Byte) As Double
        Return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) / 255
    End Function

    Private Sub btBrowesIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btBrowesIn.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        tbInPic.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End Sub

    Private Sub btBrowesOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btBrowesOut.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog()
        tbInPic.Text = FolderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath
    End Sub

    Private Sub btGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btGo.Click
        Dim Infiles As Array
        Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog

        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"
        If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName)
            Dim MyBitmap As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
            PictureBox2.Image = ConvertTo1Bit(MyBitmap)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried searching here for this?

Comment: Yes, everything I saw was for monitoring CPU usage or lowering it.

Comment: Maybe update your question with the method(s) for dealing with these images.  Would agree that it sounds pretty slow considering the CPU usage.  You could also look at multi threading, where you could process each image on it's own thread

Comment: Without seeing your code, how can we possibly hope to make it faster?...

Comment: Hursey, That looks interesting.  Googling it to see how I can apply Multi-Threading to the program

Answer (score 3):

> The program will be used to do 100 to 300 images per batch.

You can process the images asynchronously. .Net provides several ways to do this: Async/Await, raw Tasks, ThreadPool, raw Threads, BackgroundWorker, probably more. Which is most appropriate here depends on the context of the application.